# How to convert string to React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, components

I have a data fetched from the backend, and it includes the Component names, they should be passed to an HOC and to Route

```
import Users from './Users/Users.lazy';
........

 // RequireAuth is the HOC
 <Switch>
     <Route path="/home" component={RequireAuth(Home)} />
     {(props.pagesData.length) && props.pagesData.map(item =>
         <Route exact path={`${item.PagePath}`} component={RequireAuth(`${item.PageName}`)} />
     )}

     <Redirect to="/home" />
 </Switch>
```

How can I convert the string like `Users` (provided by `item.PageName`) into a Component.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ternary operator. Like this;

```
 <Route exact path={`${item.PagePath}`} component={RequireAuth(item.PagePath === 'Users' ? Users : null)} />
```

Comment: This could be my final resort, but this could be a problem because I would have a lot of Pages/Components, that's why I stored them in the database. Thanks

Comment: How about having a component map?

Comment: I think I would use your solution, since converting the string to Component can be a security risk. Thanks